DatePicker Validation - Native iOS - Swift
Here is the code that I have done in native iOS Swift:
class DateFilterViewController: BaseViewController, DateFilterView {

// MARK: - Private properties
@IBOutlet weak var crossButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var segmentView: UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var startLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var startDateField: BorderedTextField?
@IBOutlet weak var endLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var endDateField: BorderedTextField?
@IBOutlet weak var mainButton: UIButton?

var segementControl: UISegmentedControl?
private let appearance: DateFilterAppearance?
private let datePickerStart = UIDatePicker()
private let datePickerEnd = UIDatePicker()
private var isSelectedSegment = false
private var startSelectedDate = Date()
private var endSelectedDate = Date()
private let dash = DateUtil.dashDataFormat, slash = DateUtil.slashDataFormat

// MARK: - Public properties
var output: DateFilterViewOutput!

// MARK: - Initialization / Deinitialization
init(appearance: DateFilterAppearance?) {
    self.appearance = appearance
    super.init(nibName: "DateFilterView", bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

// MARK: - UIViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = localizedKey(key: "title")
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    if let display = self.appearance {
        setViewAppearance(appearance: display)
    }
    startDateField?.dropdownButton(completionHandler: {
        if let field = self.startDateField {
            self.callDatePicker(textField: field)
        }
    })
    endDateField?.dropdownButton(completionHandler: {
        if let field = self.endDateField {
            self.callDatePicker(textField: field)
        }
    })
}

// MARK: - DateFilterView
var dates: [Dates]? = [] {
    didSet {
    }
}
var confirmDates: Dates? {
    didSet {
        output.confirmDates = confirmDates
    }
}

private func callDatePicker(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.keyboardToolbar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    if textField == startDateField {
        datePickerStart.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            datePickerStart.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        }
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        textField.inputView = datePickerStart
        datePickerStart.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleStartDatePicker), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        textField.addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(self, action: #selector(donePickerStart))
        if let sDate = showSelectedDate(textField: textField) {
            datePickerStart.date = sDate
        }
    } else {
        datePickerEnd.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            datePickerEnd.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        }
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        textField.inputView = datePickerEnd
        datePickerEnd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEndDatePicker), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        textField.addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(self, action: #selector(donePickerEnd))
        if let eDate = showSelectedDate(textField: textField) {
            datePickerEnd.date = eDate
        }
    }
}

private func showSelectedDate(textField: UITextField) -> Date? {
    if let sDateString = textField.text, sDateString.count > 0 {
        return DateUtil.getDateFromString(string: sDateString, timeFormat: DateUtil.slashDataFormat)
    }
    return nil
}

// MARK: - Private methods
@objc private func donePickerStart() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    guard let sDate = startDateField?.text, !sDate.isEmpty else {
        self.startDateField?.text = DateUtil.convertStringFromDate(date: datePickerStart.date)
        return
    }
}

@objc private func donePickerEnd() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    guard let eDate = endDateField?.text, !eDate.isEmpty else {
        self.endDateField?.text = DateUtil.convertStringFromDate(date: datePickerEnd.date)
        return
    }
}

private func validateDate() {
    guard let sDate = startDateField?.text, !sDate.isEmpty else {
        let sRequire = localizedKey(key: "from.require")
        self.displayMessage(title: "", message: sRequire, actions: [MessageAction.okAction()])
        return
    }
    guard let eDate = endDateField?.text, !eDate.isEmpty else {
        let sRequire = localizedKey(key: "to.require")
        self.displayMessage(title: "", message: sRequire, actions: [MessageAction.okAction()])
        return
    }
}

@IBAction func onClickConfirmButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let sDate = startDateField?.text, !sDate.isEmpty, let eDate = endDateField?.text, !eDate.isEmpty else {
        validateDate(); return
    }
    if startSelectedDate > endSelectedDate {
        let invalid = localizedKey(key: "invalid.date")
        self.displayMessage(title: "", message: invalid, actions: [MessageAction.okAction()])
        return
    }
    if let val = segementControl?.isSelected, val == true {
        if let selectedSegment = segementControl?.selectedSegmentIndex {
            confirmDates = dates?[selectedSegment]
        }
    } else {
        guard let startText = startDateField?.text, let endText = endDateField?.text else {
            return
        }
        let startVal = DateUtil.convert(filledDate: startText, fromFormat: slash, intoFormat: dash)
        let endVal = DateUtil.convert(filledDate: endText, fromFormat: slash, intoFormat: dash)

        confirmDates = Dates(filterId: -1, name: "", start: startVal, end: endVal, mobileName: "")
        output.dismissView(view: self)
        return
    }
    output.dismissView(view: self)
}

@IBAction func onchangeDateSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    segementControl?.isSelected = true
    let index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    if let dateValue = dates?[index] {
        startDateField?.text = DateUtil.convert(filledDate: dateValue.start, fromFormat: dash, intoFormat: slash)
        endDateField?.text = DateUtil.convert(filledDate: dateValue.end, fromFormat: dash, intoFormat: slash)
    }

}

private func localizedKey(key: String) -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: "DateFilter", comment: "")
}

@IBAction func onclickCrossButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    output.dismissView(view: self)
}

private func setSegmentControlContents(dates: [Dates], confirmDates: Dates?) {

    var items = [String]()
    dates.forEach({items.append($0.mobileName)})
    let segmentController = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    segmentView?.addSubview(segmentController)
    segmentController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onchangeDateSegment), for: .valueChanged)
    segmentController.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top)
    segmentController.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .leading)
    segmentController.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .trailing)
    segmentController.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .bottom)
    segmentController.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    segmentController.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    segmentController.setTitleTextAttributes(self.appearance?.selectedDateFont, for: .selected)
    segmentController.setTitleTextAttributes(self.appearance?.unSelectedDateFont, for: .normal)
    segementControl = segmentController
    if dates.contains(where: {$0.mobileName == confirmDates?.mobileName}) {
        if let index = dates.firstIndex(where: {$0.mobileName == confirmDates?.mobileName}) {
            segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = index
            segementControl?.isSelected = true
        }
    }
}

private func setViewAppearance(appearance: DateFilterAppearance) {
    startDateField?.configureAppearance(appearance.textAppearance, fieldAppearanceType: .dropDown)
    startDateField?.borderedEdges = BorderedEdge.all
    startDateField?.delegate = self
    startDateField?.placeholder = localizedKey(key: "from")

    endDateField?.configureAppearance(appearance.textAppearance, fieldAppearanceType: .dropDown)
    endDateField?.borderedEdges = BorderedEdge.all
    endDateField?.delegate = self
    endDateField?.placeholder = localizedKey(key: "to")

    mainButton?.configureAppearance(appearance.mainButtonAppearance, title: localizedKey(key: "mainButton.title"))

    startLabel?.configureAppearance(appearance.formLabel)
    endLabel?.configureAppearance(appearance.formLabel)
        output.confirmDates = confirmDates
    let start = confirmDates?.start ?? "", end = confirmDates?.end ?? ""
    startDateField?.text = DateUtil.convert(filledDate: start, fromFormat: dash, intoFormat: slash)
    endDateField?.text = DateUtil.convert(filledDate: end, fromFormat: dash, intoFormat: slash)
    if let data = dates {
        setSegmentControlContents(dates: data, confirmDates: confirmDates)
    }
}

@objc func handleStartDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    segementControl?.isSelected = false
    segementControl?.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
    startSelectedDate = sender.date
    self.startDateField?.text = DateUtil.convertStringFromDate(date: sender.date)
}

@objc func handleEndDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    segementControl?.isSelected = false
    segementControl?.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
    endSelectedDate = sender.date
    self.endDateField?.text = DateUtil.convertStringFromDate(date: sender.date)
}
}

extension DateFilterViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        callDatePicker(textField: textField)
    }
}

The Issue is in below flow:

I have selected startDate as "07/23/24" (i.e 23rd July 2024)
I have selected endDate as "07/23/24" (i.e. 23rd July 2024)

works fine no issue.
then
3. I have selected endDate as "07/24/24" (i.e. 24th July 2024)
It displays Validation Popup as "StartDate cannot be greater than EndDate"
Code :
if startSelectedDate > endSelectedDate {
        let invalid = localizedKey(key: "invalid.date")
        self.displayMessage(title: "", message: invalid, actions: [MessageAction.okAction()])
        return
    }

inside onClickConfirmButton button.
In this case popup should not be display as It is setting 07/23/23 on startDate Field and 07/24/24 on endDate Filed.
The issue is in startSelectedDate and endSelectedDate Values.
I am getting values as below:
startSelectedDate : 2024-10-14 13:51:13 +0000
endSelectedDate : 2024-07-23 18:30:00 +0000

It would be a lot easier for us to help you if you provided a minimum reproducible example.  There seems to be a lot of superfluous code in there, that makes it very hard to follow the flow, while one of the key parts - DateUtil - is missing.

I have selected startDate as "07/23/24" ... endDate as "07/23/24" -- I am getting values as below: startSelectedDate : 2024-10-14 13:51:13 +0000 endSelectedDate : 2024-07-23 18:30:00 +0000 ... 2024-10-14 is not equal to July 23, 2024

Can you please post how you are converting the date back and forth. What is DateUtil.getDateFromString(string: sDateString, timeFormat: DateUtil.slashDataFormat)

It might be the issue with the locale (07/23/23 versus 23/07/23), try to set local programmatically
private func setupDatePickers() {
    let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // Use a consistent locale for both date pickers
    let timeZone = TimeZone.current // Or specify a fixed time zone, e.g., TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    
    datePickerStart.locale = locale
    datePickerStart.timeZone = timeZone
    datePickerEnd.locale = locale
    datePickerEnd.timeZone = timeZone
}

